# Generics incompatible types

Tags: java

Stumbled upon incompatible types error cause of which I don't understand.

Why is this piece of code wrong?

```
List<List<String>> a = new ArrayList<>();
List b = a; // is ok
List<List> c = a; // incompatible types
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html).
Supertype compatibility works only on the 'outer' level, but not 'inside' across the type parameters. It is not intuitive, but that's how it works...
In addition, `List` is a raw type, and it behaves slightly differently than `List<Object>` - which is described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
List<List>
```

is implicitly

`List<List<Object>>`

which is not a parent of

```
List<List<String>>
```

the reason why it succeeds in the first case is because of Type Inference. 
The compiler will essentially check which type is needed for the expression to make sense and it will generate

```
List<List<String>> a = b;
```

In the second case it will default to

```
List<List<Object>> a = b // which does not compile
```

Comment: I got that, but why the second line doesn't give a compile time error, since it can lead to the same runtime errors as the 3rd line?

Comment: That is exactly the reason why you should prefer generics over raw types. The generic code guarantees you type-safety in this case, the raw code doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Writing

```
List b = a;
```

Doesn't involves generics. It defines a raw List type named b which can take any object as it's element.

Don't compare it with

```
List<List> c = a;
```

as it involves generics and that's why compiler will enforce type compatibility checking here.

Comment: Yes, but if further in code we will call b.add(new Object()); it will throw runtime error since we will basically do a.add(new Object());
My question now is why does 3rd line prevent accidental errors by giving errors in compile time, while 2nd one doesn't

Comment: That runtime error is not related to our disscussion of type compatibility checking.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: because your `c` list contains a list with all kind of objects.
For example you can also add `Integer` objects.
And `a` list can contains only `String` objects.